# StanfordNlp parser stops at first sentence

Tags: python, parsing, stanford-nlp

I have problem with python Stanford nlp, sentence parsing and writing it on file.
Problem: I have .txt file with few sentences and using for loop I want to parse all sentences. Problem is that using StanfordCoreNlp parsing works just for first sentence and not for all. It just stops parsing and writing.

Example:
**File(sentences2.txt):** The still, chill mist of the January morning veiled a remote sun. Down in the corner, where a drift of snowdrops bloomed in the winter cold, four children chattered in excited conference. They were careless of the cold, dressed unsuitably for the icy weather. They giggled in conspiracy and then suddenly their huddled group burst apart in playful exuberance. Three ran in different directions. There were plenty of hiding places, for the area was dotted with trees, shrubs and stones.

**Code:**

```
from stanfordcorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP

nlp = StanfordCoreNLP(r"C:\Users\user\Downloads\stanford-corenlp-full-2017-06-09\stanford-corenlp-full-2017-06-09")

test_sent = open("C:/Users/user/Desktop/Test sentences2.txt", "r",
                    encoding="iso-8859-1")

output = open("C:/Users/user/Desktop/Output2.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8")
lines = test_sent.readlines()

for line in lines:
    output.write(nlp.parse(line))

test_sent2.close()
output2.close()
```

**File(output2.txt):**

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP
      (NP (DT The) (RB still))
      (, ,)
      (NP
        (NP (NN chill) (NN mist))
        (PP (IN of)
          (NP (DT the) (NNP January) (NN morning)))))
    (VP (VBD veiled)
      (NP (DT a) (JJ remote) (NN sun)))
    (. .)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file contents is exactly as you posted, you have no new-line characters in it, so the `readlines()` returns only one line, containing all the sentences. `parse()` stops at the first sentence, so you're feeding it all the sentences at once, but it only parses the first one.

Two options:

## Option 1: Fix the file

Insert line breaks after every sentence, that should solve your issue.

## Option 2: Change the code

Instead of using `parse()` call `annotate()`:

```
lines = test_sent.read()

output.write(nlp.annotate(line))
```

You can choose your annotators, language and output format by passing a *properties* parameter, as explained [here](https://github.com/Lynten/stanford-corenlp#general-stanford-corenlp-api). It is also recommended to increase the memory allocated to `StanfordCoreNLP`:

```
nlp = StanfordCoreNLP(r'path_to_corenlp', memory='8g')
```

Comment: Thank you Yigal! This is helpful. Now I know how to use properties parameters. Problem with annotate is that it doesn't write output in format as in example (output2.txt). Tried different properties but result is different from original. Maybe you know right combination of parameters?

Comment: Did you try asking it to _parse_ and write output in _text_? For example `props={'annotators': 'parse','pipelineLanguage':'en','outputFormat':'text'}`

Comment: If I change output format to json or xml, than everything works but text somehow doesn't

Comment: This is the error (it repeats its self): WARNING:urllib3.response:Received response with both Content-Length and Transfer-Encoding set. This is expressly forbidden by RFC 7230 sec 3.3.2. Ignoring Content-Length and attempting to process response as Transfer-Encoding: chunked.

Comment: And there's no valid content after that warning? Also did you try working with the JSON output? Should be better for programmatic manipulation.

Comment: No unfortunately there is not. I tried json but result is much different. Thank you for your help, Yigal